# Where to find the file to run odoo

Tags: odoo

I installed odoo 10 on centos 7 from:
http://nightly.odoo.com/10.0/nightly/rpm/
[image]
I can't find the file to run odoo from.
Thank you for any help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlDmb.png)

Answer (score 0):

If not is not available just create a python file example(odoo-server.py) under `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo`, paste the following code and run.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import odoo

if __name__ == "__main__":
    odoo.cli.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this file in /usr/bin called odoo
and i can run odoo like: ./usr/bin/odoo